# Change Image Design color Fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-fabric

[1](http://demo.infinityfashion.co.in/)i have to change active object image color currently my t-shirt color is changing but when i add design on it i am unable to change color of.

My Code To change Tshirt Color :

```
//setup front side canvas
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tcanvas', {
    hoverCursor: 'pointer',
    selection: true,
    selectionBorderColor: 'blue'
});
canvas.on({
    'object:moving': function(e) {
        e.target.opacity = 0.5;
    },
    'object:modified': function(e) {
        e.target.opacity = 1;
    },
    'object:selected': onObjectSelected,
    'selection:cleared': onSelectedCleared
});
$('.color-preview').click(function(){
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
    document.getElementById("shirtDiv").style.backgroundColor = color;
    $('.shirtDivs').css('background-color',color);
});
```

HERE  I Try To change Design color

```
$('#image-color').miniColors({
    change: function(hex, rgb) {
        var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (activeObject && activeObject.type === 'image') {
            activeObject.fill = this.value;
            canvas.renderAll();

        }
    },
    open: function(hex, rgb) {

    },
    close: function(hex, rgb) {

    }
});
```

[Demo](http://demo.infinityfashion.co.in/)

Comment: Is this your demo that you are providing, or is this someone else's?

Answer (score 5):

@user3810894 - I'm guessing what you are asking is how to change the background color of the **design** (gravatar in your demo).

[image]

The reason it is not taking on the color on the shirt background is because the gravatar's background color is white and not transparent.

[image]  instead of [image]

If you were to take those images and clear out the background and resave (as a PNG with transparency) then it would take on the color of the shirt when you overlayed it.

[image]

If you want to change the background color of the avatar different than the color of the shirt, then you will do the same thing - make the background transparent and then give it a background color with CSS (like how it works for the shirt in the demo)

The shirt changes "color" because it's only a transparent image of a shirt with shadows using varying degrees of transparency.

[image]

So in essence you could do it to your gravatar images as well.

Hope that helps someone.