# Change color of image based on color picker

Tags: html

I am having difficulties on where to begin for what I want to do.

I want to create an image editor on my page.  So, suppose that I have an image of a car.  Now I want to be able to change the color of each part of the car (hood, doors, wheels, etc).  So when I click on the hood of the car, I can go to a color picker and choose a color and then the hood's color will change to the color I selected.

My research has led me to using a canvas element in HTML5 but I have no idea where to begin.

I found a [perfect example](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/product/hypervenom-phantom-ii-id-shoe/?piid=42552&pbid=1086217738#?pbid=1086217738) of what I am trying to do.  User's are able to select any part of the shoe and change the color of that part of the shoe.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use JS for this. This other question seems like a good place to start. [Change Image Design color Fabric js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045911/change-image-design-color-fabric-js)